# Count the number of occurrence of every word in a c# windows forms listbox

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listbox

I want to count the number of occurrence of every word that is in a listbox.
This is my function that count the occurrence

```
public int CountWords(ArrayList list, string item)
{
    int count = 0;
    foreach (string str in list)
    {
        if (item == str)
            count++;
    }
    return count;
}
```

And this is where i use *CountWords* ->

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    listBox3.Items.Clear();
    ArrayList arrList = new ArrayList();
    int count = 0;
    foreach (object item in listBox2.Items)
    {
        arrList.Add(item);
    }

    foreach (string str in arrList)
    {
        count = obj.CountWords(arrList, str);
        listBox3.Items.Add(str + ": " + count);
    }

}
```

If in the listbox i have this values:
*hi*
*its*
*me*
*me*
the result is this:
 [image]

The counts are right but i want the result to be like this:
[image]

What should i add or remove from the code?
I'll appreciate any kind of help :)

**Edit**:
I'm not able to use the *Count()* method.

Comment: Why are you using ArrayList? Why not array or List? str.Distinct().ToList(); should remove duplicates, but returns a List.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace this

```
 foreach (string str in arrList)
        {
            count = obj.CountWords(arrList, str);
            listBox3.Items.Add(str + ": " + count);
        }
```

with this

```
 foreach (string str in arrList)
                {
                      string_Item=string.Concat(str,":",obj.CountWords(arrList, str));


                    if (!listBox3.Items.Contains(_Item))
                    {
                        listBox3.Items.Add(_Item);
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can count the occurrence of items simply this way:

```
listBox2.DataSource = listBox1.Items.Cast<object>().GroupBy(x => x)
                              .Select(x => $"{x.Key}:{x.Count()}").ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve your requirement very easily using Linq GroupBy

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    listBox3.Items.Clear();
    var temp = listBox2.Items.Cast<string>().GroupBy(s => s);
    foreach(var g in temp)
        listBox3.Items.Add(g.Key + ": " + g.Count());
}
```

Version without Count()

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    listBox3.Items.Clear();
    var temp = listBox2.Items.Cast<string>().GroupBy(s => s);
    foreach(var g in temp)
    {
        int count = 0; foreach(string s in g) count++;
        listBox3.Items.Add(g.Key + ": " + count);
    }
}
```

Comment: This works great but i forgot to write in the post that I cannot use the _Count()_ method.

Comment: Just add your loop then: int count = 0; foreach(string s in g) count++;

Answer (score 0):

You can use Distinct

```
foreach (string str in arrList.Distinct())
```